# How do I wait for a promise to resolve? or am I doing it wrong?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, design-patterns, promise

I have a basic helper that gets the user by username except there are instances where the promise isn't resolved yet, so getting the user by username returns null.

The following example is in Angular using coffeescript:

```
angular.module('test')
.service('UserHelper', ['User', (User) ->
    users = null
    User.getAll().$promise.then((data) ->
      users = data.users
    )

    getUserByUsername = (user) ->
      username = user.username
      index = _.findLastIndex(users, (user) ->
        user.username == username
      )
      return users[index]

    return {
      getUserByUsername: (user) ->
        return getUserByUsername(user)
    }
  ])
```

So when I call `this.getUserByUsername`, I would expect to get the user object. I don't know the proper design pattern to achieve what I want and still have it wait for the promise to be resolved before running this line `return getUserByUsername(user)`.

Comment: Promises tend to be contagious - if you have a function which uses a promise, and that function should return a value, you pretty much need to return the value wrapped in a promise. That, or busy-wait for the promise to complete.

Comment: DO NOT CODE A BUSY WAIT, just to be clear.

Comment: You don't "wait" for a Promise. You provide the promise with a function to call when it's been satisfied.

Comment: What do you want your API contract to be? Either it's synchronous, then you must return null (or throw exception) before user is retrieved. Or, it's async - then the client code would expect a promise back and `.then` it accordingly.

Comment: Also, when you're trying to construct an API around an asynchronous API, give up on the idea of being able to `return` a useful value (other than a Promise).

Comment: You can't think sequential way when dealing with asynchronous function. I will suggest return a promise instead of some value. Show how you need to call the function. People can suggest you how should it be done